# Why is the water pressure suddenly high in my toilet after hot water heater replacement?

Tags: water, water-heater, water-pressure

I got my hot water heater replaced this morning. Immediately after the water pressure in my toilet became very high. When flushed it’s so forceful I jump. I noticed a noise when the guys were still here and they said it was the toilet refilling after they turned the water off. But it hasn’t gotten better through the day. Did I just not realize my pressure was sluggish before? The other tank was about 7/8 yrs old and had a a tiny leak and some rusting.

Answer (score 4):

Try running the water for several minutes, both hot and cold sides, at the other fixtures too. Do they behave similarly? Do the symptoms diminish after a minute or two?

When a water system is opened, especially for something like a heater replacement, air gets into the pipes. Eventually the air finds its way out through the various faucets. As bubbles of air exit the faucet they make a lot of noise. They also can cause the water to eject forcefully. It sounds and looks a lot like the water pressure had been increased even though that's not actually the case. Running the faucets for a few minutes allows the air to be purged from the system and it'll behave normally again afterward.

Comment: The water did act like it had air in the pipes with the faucets and went away quickly. But the toilet is still alarming after a few flushes. Maybe I’ll just flush it occasionally and it will even out? It’s just me so it doesn’t get used that frequently.

Comment: @TenilleMarie If you flush the toilet _and continue holding the flush lever down_ the tank can't refill and the water will continue running. It might be a little easier to purge the air this way rather than repeated flushing and waiting for the tank to fill.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I experienced something similar. I installed a new and more efficient water heater. In doing so, I had to replace some of the old iron pipes. Suddenly, I no longer have water pressure problems with the shower hot water which is understandable, but the toilet starting filling and flushing better too!